# Windows custom shortcuts

Tags: vb.net, windows, visual-studio-2010, powershell

Some years ago, google was offering an exe, when installed on windows, pressing the alt (or ctl) key twice quickly would bring up a google-search-box/widget on the screen.

I am constantly switching in to text editor from other windows, so
how can I customize windows so that when I press alt key twice quickly, then
my text editor is brought to the foreground.

Comment: You should go look up AutoHotkey. It has its own (surprisingly powerful) scripting language and can make a lot of things like what you want a whole lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Windows does not have a method for executing actions based on rapid succession of characters. AutoHotKey (AHK) is a good scripting language with a large community and I believe it can register an event similar to how you described.

Just a quick search finds this, would shows a proof of concept.

[AutoHotKey rapid hotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/35566-rapidhotkey/)